# Catch error if retryWhen:s retries runs out

Tags: rx-java, reactive-programming

In the [documentation for RetryWhen](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/retry.html) the example there goes like this:

```
Observable.create((Subscriber<? super String> s) -> {
  System.out.println("subscribing");
  s.onError(new RuntimeException("always fails"));
}).retryWhen(attempts -> {
  return attempts.zipWith(Observable.range(1, 3), (n, i) -> i).flatMap(i -> {
      System.out.println("delay retry by " + i + " second(s)");
      return Observable.timer(i, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
  });
}).toBlocking().forEach(System.out::println);
```

But how do I propagate the Error if the retries runs out?

Adding `.doOnError(System.out::println)` *after* the `retryWhen` clause does not catch the error. Is it even emitted?

Adding a `.doOnError(System.out::println)` *before* retryWhen displays `always fails` for all retries.

Answer (score 14):

The doc for `retryWhen` says that it passes `onError` notification to its subscribers and terminates. So you can do something like this:

```
    final int ATTEMPTS = 3;

    Observable.create((Subscriber<? super String> s) -> {
        System.out.println("subscribing");
        s.onError(new RuntimeException("always fails"));
    }).retryWhen(attempts -> attempts
            .zipWith(Observable.range(1, ATTEMPTS), (n, i) ->
                    i < ATTEMPTS ?
                            Observable.timer(i, SECONDS) :
                            Observable.error(n))
            .flatMap(x -> x))
            .toBlocking()
            .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Answer (score 7):

The [Javadoc](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/Observable.html#retryWhen(rx.functions.Func1)) for `retryWhen` states that:

> If that Observable calls onComplete or onError then retry will call
>   onCompleted or onError on the child subscription.

Put simply, if you want to propagate the exception, you'll need to rethrow the original exception once you've had enough retrying.

An easy way is to set your `Observable.range` to be 1 greater than the number of times you want to retry.

Then in your zip function test the current number of retries. If it's equal to NUMBER_OF_RETRIES + 1, return `Observable.error(throwable)` or re-throw your exception.

EG

```
Observable.create((Subscriber<? super String> s) -> {
            System.out.println("subscribing");
            s.onError(new RuntimeException("always fails"));
        }).retryWhen(attempts -> {
            return attempts.zipWith(Observable.range(1, NUMBER_OF_RETRIES + 1), (throwable, attempt) -> {
                if (attempt == NUMBER_OF_RETRIES + 1) {
                    throw Throwables.propagate(throwable);
                }
                else {
                    return attempt;
                }
            }).flatMap(i -> {
                System.out.println("delaying retry by " + i + " second(s)");
                return Observable.timer(i, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            });
        }).toBlocking().forEach(System.out::println);
```

As an aside `doOnError` does not affect the Observable in any way - it simply provides you with a hook to perform some action if an error occurs. A common example is logging.

Answer (score 1):

One option is using `Observable.materialize()` to convert `Observable.range()` items into notifications. Then once `onCompleted()` is issued, one can propagate error downstream (in sample below `Pair` is used to wrap `Observable.range()` notifications and exception from `Observable`)

```
   @Test
   public void retryWhen() throws Exception {

    Observable.create((Subscriber<? super String> s) -> {
        System.out.println("subscribing");
        s.onError(new RuntimeException("always fails"));
    }).retryWhen(attempts -> {
        return attempts.zipWith(Observable.range(1, 3).materialize(), Pair::new)
           .flatMap(notifAndEx -> {
            System.out.println("delay retry by " + notifAndEx + " second(s)");
            return notifAndEx.getRight().isOnCompleted()
                    ? Observable.<Integer>error(notifAndEx.getLeft())
                    : Observable.timer(notifAndEx.getRight().getValue(), TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        });
    }).toBlocking().forEach(System.out::println);
}

    private static class Pair<L,R> {
        private final L left;
        private final R right;

        public Pair(L left, R right) {
            this.left = left;
            this.right = right;
        }

        public L getLeft() {
            return left;
        }

        public R getRight() {
            return right;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the behaviour you want using the `RetryWhen` builder in [rxjava-extras](https://github.com/davidmoten/rxjava-extras) which is on Maven Central. Use the latest version.

```
Observable.create((Subscriber<? super String> s) -> {
    System.out.println("subscribing");
    s.onError(new RuntimeException("always fails"));
}) 
.retryWhen(RetryWhen
   .delays(Observable.range(1, 3)
               .map(n -> (long) n), 
            TimeUnit.SECONDS).build())
.doOnError(e -> e.printStackTrace()) 
.toBlocking().forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: Um, why the down-vote? This is a unit tested library.

Answer (score 0):

This is the simplest way I find to implement it in Kotlin. Retries `maxRetries` times and if there was no successful attempts, passes the error to the source of `onErrorResumeNext`.

```
api.getItems()
        .retryWhen { errors ->
            errors.zipWith(Observable.range(1, maxRetries + 1), { error, i ->
                if (i <= maxRetries) {
                    Observable.timer(i.toLong(), TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                } else {
                    throw error
                }
            })
        }.onErrorResumeNext { error ->
            return@onErrorResumeNext Observable.error(factory.create(error))
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to use **onErrorResumeNext** after the retryWhen

In your example

```
    Observable.create((Subscriber<? super String> s) -> {
        System.out.println("subscribing");
        s.onError(new RuntimeException("always fails"));
    }).retryWhen(attempts -> {
        return attempts.zipWith(Observable.range(1, NUMBER_OF_RETRIES + 1), (n, i) -> {
            if (i == NUMBER_OF_RETRIES + 1) {
                throw Throwables.propagate(n);
            }
            else {
                return i;
            }
        }).flatMap(i -> {
            System.out.println("delay retry by " + i + " second(s)");
            return Observable.timer(i, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        });
    })
    .onErrorResumeNext(t -> {System.out.println("Error after all retries:" + t.getMessage());
                                              return Observable.error(t);
                                          })
    .toBlocking().forEach(System.out::println);
```

At the bottom of this class you can see a practical example to understand how works. https://github.com/politrons/reactive/blob/master/src/test/java/rx/observables/errors/ObservableExceptions.java

Answer (score -1):

You can either use scan function, which returns a pair with accumulated index and decide whether or not to pass on the error:

```
.retryWhen(attempts -> 
    return .scan(Pair.create(0, null), (index, value) -> Pair.create(index.first + 1, value))
            .flatMap(pair -> {
                if(pair.first > MAX_RETRY_COUNT) {
                    throw new RuntimeException(pair.second);
                }
                return Observable.timer(pair.first, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            });
```

Or you can stick with `zipWith` operator but increase the number in `range` Observable and return a pair, instead of the index alone. That way, you won't loose the information about previous `throwable`.

```
attempts
    .zipWith(Observable.range(1, MAX_RETRY_COUNT + 1), (throwable, i) -> Pair.create(i, throwable))
    .flatMap(pair -> {
        if(pair.first > MAX_RETRY_COUNT) throw new RuntimeException(pair.second);
        System.out.println("delay retry by " + pair.first + " second(s)");
        return Observable.timer(pair.first, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    });
```