# can I use retryWhen and return an observable when a limit is reached?

Tags: java, observable, rx-java

I am trying to do a retry with java Rx (version 1).

I want to do a `retryWhen` instead of a simple `retry()` because I want when the limit is reached return an observable with certain value rather than just throw an exception.

So, checking this https://blog.danlew.net/2016/01/25/rxjavas-repeatwhen-and-retrywhen-explained/ and this [Catch error if retryWhen:s retries runs out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37860856/catch-error-if-retrywhens-retries-runs-out) I was able to build something that helps my purpose.

```
// this is only to simulate the real method that will possibly throw an exception
public static Observable<String> test() {
    Observable<String> var = Observable.error(new IOException());
    return var;
}


Observable<String> test = test().retryWhen(attempts -> {
    return attempts.zipWith(Observable.range(1, 3), (throwable, attempt) -> {
        if (attempt == 3) {
            LOG.info("attempting");
            return Observable.just("completed with error");
        } else {
            return attempt;
        }
    });
});



test.doOnError(x -> System.out.println("do on error message")).subscribe(s -> {
    System.out.println(s);
});
```

when I run this locally, I see the logging of attempting 3 times (as expected).

I don't see the `println "do on error message"` (as expected)

But I do **not** see the `completed with error` which I was expecting, makes me doubt I actually return the observable I want or not, what am I doing wrong?

I also don't understand why it allows me to return an observable and an integer inside **zipWith**. Any ideas?

and, is it possible to throw the exception/error from my own observable definition? something like this:

```
Observable<String> test = test().retry(3).map(value -> {
// some logic to define what to do
Observable.error(new Exception("error");
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly,

> I also don't understand why it allows me to return an observable and an integer inside zipWith.

The signature of the lambda in `zipWith` is `(Throwable, Integer) -> Object` meaning that anything is a valid return as it is a child of `Object`. This is the case since this function is defining how to combine the two objects (in this case the `Throwable` and `Integer`, and any `Object` is a valid combination (or lack thereof).

Back to your main issue. It is important to remember what `retryWhen` is actually doing. This is a bit tricky (at least for me) to understand, but basically whenever the observer in the body of `retryWhen` emits, that causes the upstream `Observable` to be re-subscribed to. This does not control the downstream emission.

The examples from the [docs](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/io/reactivex/Observable.html#retryWhen-io.reactivex.functions.Function-) (an RxJava 2 snippet, but the sentiment should still apply) show this:

```
  Observable.create((ObservableEmitter<? super String> s) -> {
      System.out.println("subscribing");
      s.onError(new RuntimeException("always fails"));
  }).retryWhen(attempts -> {
      return attempts.zipWith(Observable.range(1, 3), (n, i) -> i).flatMap(i -> {
          System.out.println("delay retry by " + i + " second(s)");
          return Observable.timer(i, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
      });
  }).blockingForEach(System.out::println);
```

In this example the return in the `retryWhen` block is controlling when we resubscribe to the initial source. In this case we are saying that we want to delay re-subscription for `i` seconds.

With this in mind, `retryWhen` may not be the solution you initially seek. Another solution could be using a `retry` with however many times you want to attempt your subscription (or a `retryWhen` if you want anything with a more customized re-subscription), and then use [`onErrorResumeNext`](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/Error-Handling-Operators#onerrorresumenext). See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45885416/mapping-exception-in-rxjava-2).

As an example:

```
Observable.create((ObservableEmitter<String> s) -> s.onError(new RuntimeException("always fails")))
        .retry(3)
        .onErrorResumeNext(throwable -> {
            return Observable.just("hi");
        })
        .subscribe(System.out::println, System.out::println);
```

The resulting output is `hi`. The key here is that `onErrorResumeNext` allows us to turn our emitted exceptions into something else. Almost like a `map` for exceptions.

Comment: is it possible to throw the exception from a defined on the observable? Im updating my question with more detrails

Comment: @jpganz18 it's not clear what your trying to do in that updated question example with the `map`